# Get Google Oauth for Google Calendar to work in 2016

Tags: ios, oauth, calendar, google-api

It seems that Google is cool with their current tutorials directions being outdated for weeks and months at a time. Ive yet to find a simple working sample of how to let a user oauth with google and get access to calendar api's anyone have a clue on this? Im 2 days and a bottle of Excedrin deep at this point, begging for mercy on my soul.  Here is what ive tried:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/additional-scopes#before_you_begin   -seems to work , but not for accessing calendar

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios  - Outdated, ive yet to find anyone claiming to of gotten this set of examples to work, googles official response on Github issues can be summed up as "opps....yeah bro, sorry bout that will get to it eventually were overhauling everything over the next few months."

I just want a simple, easy to follow way to get access to gCal api.